# How to use a JavaScript function inside an .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a javascript function inside an `html()` The codes looks like

```
 var test = getParameterByName('page');
 $(".pageContainer").html("<?php echo check("+ test")['content']; ?>  ");
```

I have tried a lot of different combinations, none works. I am new with javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use document ready in your script tag and then use your javascript

Comment: You need to write this code in php file itself.

Comment: php code will not work in javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix javascript and php like this. Javascript works in clint side while php works in server side.

You could use ajax to ask the server for the response.

***Javascript side:***

```
var test = getParameterByName('page');
$(".pageContainer").load('foo.php?key=' + encodeURIComponent(test));
```

***PHP side:***

```
<?php
// foo.php

// do something ....

echo check($_GET['key'])['content'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the `<?php` is not processed by the server before JavaScript can touch it, that should work: JavaScript will get the parameter and change the HTML of all elements of class `pageContainer` to

```
<?php echo check(X)['content']; ?>
```

where `X` is the result of `getParameterByName`. However, I can't think of a legitimate reason to put that in some HTML. More likely, you want to execute a **PHP** function, *not* a **JavaScript** function. If that's the case, it's not that simple; you'll have to create a new PHP page for the sole purpose of executing that function and use AJAX to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".pageContainer").html(check(test)['content']);
```

If you **need javascript function inside an html()** then your `js check()` should `return an array` like,

```
function check(test){
   var arr=[];
   // your code
   arr['content']='some value';
   return arr;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BpRLb/)

If `check()` is a `php function` then you need to use [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like,

```
$(function(){
    var test='your value';
    $.ajax({
       url:'function.php',
       dataType:'json',
       data:{action:'check',test:test},
       type:'POST',
       success:function(data){
          $(".pageContainer").html(data.content);
       }
    });
});
```

**Function.php page**

```
<?php
    $action=isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'check'){
       echo json_encode(array('content'=>$_REQUEST['test']));
       return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I see, but the check() is an PHP function, i just need this value from JavaScript function getParameterByName()

Comment: Ok, do it solve it? I want the value into check($VALUE) to return something. My $VALUE is returned from a JavaScript function.

Comment: Tried it, just fetch the number. I still need like:
<?php echo check(NUMBER); ?>

Comment: hi I have commented below plz check that

Comment: Now what is `number`? which you want to pass in check function?

Answer (score 0):

The .html() function within jQuery will accept a function as an argument. See https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2 So, using your example:

```
$(".pageContainer").html( function() {
    //Get the html content you are looking for
    //Perhaps $.get() [https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/] is what you 
    //are looking for instead of using php inline here
});
```

Also, .getParameterByName() is not a built in function to javascript or jQuery. To replicate it, see this answer: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

if you want get value from php function then try following

you can pass js variables as argument in php function code edited

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var param=' value from js print in php';    
$(".pageContainer").html(" <?php echo te('"+param+"'); ?>");    

}); <?php
function te($param){
    echo $param;
}
?>
```

or if you want to get value from js itself then try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
 $(".pageContainer").html( te());   

});
function te(){
    return "value from js";
}
```